# One to many relationship, find groups that contain only the specified values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, relational-division

So lets say I have a table

```
ID  Car
1   Polo
2   Jetta
```

And a one-many relationship like

```
Id  Driver  Car
1   Jason   1
2   Fred    1
2   Fred    2
3   Batman  1
4   Frodo   2
```

How can I get records from car that Only has Fred and Frodo driving it?
I.e. the query needs to return only car 2.

Comment: Your requirement is still vague. What happens if there is another driver that drives car 2. Say you also have the tuple (id, driver, car) => (5, Sam, 2). Now should the query return, car 2 or empty result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that ***only has** Fred and Frodo driving it* means Fred, Frodo and no other, you would write:

```
SELECT car
FROM car_driver
GROUP BY car
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN driver IN ('Fred', 'Frodo') THEN 1 END) = 2
AND COUNT(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the set operator [INTERSECT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm):

```
SELECT car FROM drivers WHERE driver = 'Fred'
INTERSECT
SELECT car FROM drivers WHERE driver = 'Frodo'
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=da1e51aa35c1a80bd3437fe8e4f8b5c9)

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this

```
select c.car 
from cardriver cd join cars c
   on c.id=cd.car and cd.Driver in ('Fred','Frodo')
group by c.car
   having count(distinct cd.Driver)=2
```

[db fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=416724c2159c7aef898d8c22331a7d57)